# angularjs ui-router resolve factory undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've followed the examples on the UI-Router wiki and the sample here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router
but the resolved factory is undefined when it is injected into the controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

app
    var app = angular.module('toa', ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            '' : {
              templateUrl: 'app/partials/home-partial.html'  
            },
            'sidebar@home': {
                templateUrl: 'loginMenu.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            },
            'content@home': {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            }
        }
    }).state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        views: {
            '': { templateUrl: 'app/partials/register-partial.html' },
            'content@register': {
                resolve: {
                    registerService: 'registerService'
                },
                templateUrl: 'app/views/registerView.html',
                controller: 'regController'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

controller

```
app.controller('regController', ['$scope', '$location', '$resource', '$http', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $resource, $http, registerService){
   // Controller code is here console.log(registerService) prints undefined
}
```

service

```
app.factory('registerService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        registerPlayer : function(playerName, playerPassword, playerEmail, playerGender) {
            var newPlayer = {
                ...
            };
            $http.post('...', newPlayer).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                });
        },
        checkEmail : function(emailIn) {
            var data = { email : emailIn };
            return $http.post('...', data).
                then(function(data) {
                    return data;
                });
        },
        checkUsername : function(usernameIn) {
            var data = { username : usernameIn };
            return $http.post('...', data).
                then(function(data) {
                    return data;
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: My issue has been solved, I needed to remove $route and $routeParams. Completely over looked that. Thank you for the replies, both were useful as they made me look closer at syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to declare `registerService` after `$http` in array notation of the controller definition.

If you want to inject something using resolve block in route configuration then you need to provide a function returning somthing, like Promise, or just a value. In your case try this:

```
resolve: {
    registerService: function(registerService) {
        return registerService;
    }
},
```

However note, that in your case you can simply inject service directly to controller, as you don't need resolve it here:

```
app.controller('regController', ['$scope', '$location', '$resource', '$http', 'registerService', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $resource, $http, registerService) {
   // Controller code is here console.log(registerService) prints undefined
}
```

Comment: I originally had it injected directly into the controller until I switched to angluar ui-router. After switching the service was undefined so I tried to use resolve like in the examples. I should also note that the service worked an intended before as well.

Answer (score 0):

`resolve` must be dict with functions, not a strings.

Change `registerService: 'registerService'` to some like this:

```
registerService: function (){
      //here goes your resolve function.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in resolving a service you can already inject. I think there is a conflict between the name of the service declared at your module level, and the name of the resolved-dependency, and so angular is lost.

Resolve would be interesting if you'd want to registerUser or checkEmail before entering your controller.

I suggest you remove the resolve part, and then be sure to include the  'registerService' string before your function declaration.